# "Attempting to register an unknown factory" in model test

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I have these models in an ember-cli app:

```
var PuzzleRound = DS.Model.extend({
    year: DS.attr('number')
});

var Puzzle = DS.Model.extend({
    puzzleRounds: DS.hasMany('puzzleRound', {async: true})
});
```

And here's my test from `tests/unit/models/puzzle-test.js`:

```
import {
    moduleForModel,
    test
} from 'ember-qunit';
import PuzzleRound from 'weather-roulette/models/puzzle-round';

moduleForModel('puzzle', 'Puzzle', {
    // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
    needs: ['model:puzzleRound']
});

test('it exists', function() {
    var model = this.subject();
    // var store = this.store();    
    ok(!!model);               
});
```

I get this error when running `ember test`:

```
Attempting to register an unknown factory: `model:puzzleRound`
```

I'm using ember-cli 0.1.1, Ember.js 1.7.0, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.11. Does anyone have anything I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried out this code with ember-cli 0.0.44 and I got the same error that you did.

I renamed both references to the `puzzleRound` model path to `puzzle-round` and then your test passed for me. So:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  puzzleRounds: DS.hasMany('puzzle-round', {async: true})
});
```

and

```
moduleForModel('puzzle', 'Puzzle', {
  needs: ['model:puzzle-round']
});
```

I knew that the hyphenated style was preferred over the camelCase style, but I'm not sure when this became mandatory. This requirement may be specific to ember-cli or ember-qunit.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution similar to this one for awhile, and did not see any mention of my solution so I thought I would post here anyways. It's quite simple really: make sure that the controller you're referencing is actually there.

```
// my-ember-application/tests/unit/controllers/index/bar-test.js
moduleFor('controller:index/bar', 'My Bar Test', {
    beforeEach() { .. }
});

test('it exists', function (assert) { 
    assert.ok(true); 
});
```

This code would reference a controller at this location:

`my-ember-application/app/controllers/index/bar.js`